# Problems when solving a system of PDEs with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, system

I am currently attempting to solve the following exercise question using NDSolve directly (ref.: Davis, M. E. (2013). Numerical methods and modeling for chemical engineers. Courier Corporation.).

[image: First page]

[image: Second page]

However, I'm getting some results that seem to be inconsistent with reality, particularly in relation to Theta.

[image: Results for x1]

[image: Results for x2]

[image: Results for Theta]

I have attached the code I am using below. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

```
(* Parameters *)
a = {-1.74, -4.24, -3.89};
gamma = {21.6, 25.1, 22.9};
B = {5.106, 3.144, 11.16};
Pe = 5.76;
Bo = 10.97;
Bi = 2.5;
thetaw = 1;
theta0 = 1;

(* Algebraic eqns *)
k = Table[Exp[a[[i]] + gamma[[i]]*(1 - 1/theta[z, r])], {i, 1, 3}];
R = {
   k[[1]]*(1 - x1[z, r] - x2[z, r]) - k[[2]]*x1[z, r],
   k[[2]]*x1[z, r] + k[[3]]*(1 - x1[z, r] - x2[z, r])
   };

(* PDES *)
PDE1 = D[x1[z, r], z] == 
   Pe*(D[x1[z, r], r, r] + 1/r*D[x1[z, r], r]) + B[[1]]*R[[1]];
PDE2 = D[x2[z, r], z] == 
   Pe*(D[x2[z, r], r, r] + 1/r*D[x2[z, r], r]) + B[[1]]*R[[2]];
PDE3 = D[theta[z, r], z] == 
   Bo*(D[theta[z, r], r, r] + 1/r*D[theta[z, r], r]) + B[[2]]*R[[1]] +
     B[[3]]*R[[2]];

(*Boundary and initial conditions*)
eps = N[1*10^(-6)];
BC0 = {
   D[x1[z, r], r] == 0 /. r -> eps,
   D[x2[z, r], r] == 0 /. r -> eps,
   D[theta[z, r], r] == 0 /. r -> eps
   };
BC1 = {
   D[x1[z, r], r] == 0 /. r -> 1,
   D[x2[z, r], r] == 0 /. r -> 1,
   D[theta[z, r], r] == Bi*(theta[z, r] - thetaw) /. r -> 1
   };
IC = {
   x1[z, r] == 0 /. z -> 0,
   x2[z, r] == 0 /. z -> 0,
   theta[z, r] == theta0 /. z -> 0
   };

(* Solving... *)
vars = {x1[z, r], x2[z, r], theta[z, r]};
sys = Flatten[{PDE1, PDE2, PDE3, BC0, BC1, IC}];
solve = NDSolve[sys, vars, {z, 0, 1}, {r, eps, 1}];

(* Ploting *)
Plot3D[x1[z, r] /. solve, {z, 0, 1}, {r, eps, 1}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "X1"]
Plot3D[x2[z, r] /. solve, {z, 0, 1}, {r, eps, 1}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "X2"]
Plot3D[theta[z, r] /. solve, {r, eps, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All,
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "Theta"]
```

Comment: The system is unstable at large `Bi`. Try first `Bi=0.025`, and then slowly increase up to `Bi=0.25`.